# WordPress URL/Folder ReWrite using Htaccess

Tags: htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

I am trying to mask certain folder in a WordPress installation using the Htaccess file. I am aware that there are plugins available to do exactly what I want but, I do not want to add even more plugins that may have overlapping functions.

The result I am trying to achieve is :

from

1. example.com/wp-include/js/jquery/.......
2. example.com/assets/themes/........
3. example.com/assets/themes/parent_theme/......
4. example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

to

1. example.com/lib/js/jquery.......
2. example.com/assets/layouts/.......
3. example.com/assets/layouts/main/........
4. example.com/ajax

I have tried inputting the code as below but, this just breaks WP with A 500 internal error

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^lib/(.*) /wp-includes/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/layouts/(.*) /assets/themes/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/layouts/main/(.*) /assets/themes/parent_theme/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have also tried placing the code as follows but this does not provide any results at all (it does not change the 'wp-include' to 'lib')

```
# BEGIN Custom URL Folder Rewrites
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^lib/(.*) /wp-includes/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/layouts/(.*) /assets/themes/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/layouts/main/(.*) /assets/themes/parent_theme/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Custom URL Folder Rewrites
```

I would be grateful for any help in solving this problem without the use of an additional function heavy plugin.

This WP installation does not use the standard wp-content folder but a custom folder 'assets'

I would also like to be able to use the code outside of the BEGIN WordPress and END WordPress tags so that I have full control and WP does not remove or edit them.

Comment: It looks like you would run a big risk of collisions with that remapping scheme.

Comment: I know that this is possible using a plugin 'hide my wp' but, I do not want to add more plugins and the features of that plugin overlap a plugin that I am currently using and does cause issues.